# Differentiate system folders and user-created folder?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I get the list of folders in mailbox using ***https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders***.

How to differentiate  the system folders like inbox,sent items from user created folders ?

Is there any other way to classify the folders ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the ids of default folders (at least the ones you care about) and compare them with the id of a folder in question.

Answer (score 0):

It probably requires more logic in the behind.

There are well-known [folder names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailfolder?view=graph-rest-1.0) created for the users by default.

`archive`, `clutter`, `conflicts`, `conversationhistory`, `deleteditems`, `drafts`, `inbox`, `junkemail`, `localfailures`, `msgfolderroot`, `outbox`, `recoverableitemsdeletions`, `scheduled`, `searchfolders`, `sentitems`, `serverfailures`, `syncissues`

You can call the following endpoint to get detail of the well-known folder.

```
GET /me/mailFolders/{well-known-name}
```

Store an id of each well-known folder somewhere.

When you get the list of mail folders

```
GET /me/mailFolders
```

Compare the id of each folder with ids of the stored well-known folder, so you can distinguish between system folder and user created folder.

Not the best solution, maybe others will have some better idea.